# When variables not allowed to be null are actually created with no data on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I was recently adding large amounts of data from a JSON file to my Django "member" model. For this purpose I had to make most of my variables able to take in null or blank in order to handle cases when the JSON file did not have information on a specific variable etc etc.

```
event = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

tool = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)



other = models.CharField(max_length=200)

protocol = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

However, I accidentally forgot to change 2 variables for this purpose. Surprisingly my objects were generated without a problem even when the JSON data was not adding anything to this variables.

So here is my question(s):

1. How was the member object created when some variables that are not
   allowed to be null, were actually null or at the very least had no
   data.
2. I thought this restriction was at the Database level but it seems
   here like it is only for user submitted data since when I created
   the object internally it actually allowed me to have several
   null/blank variables.
3. Is Django taking care of something behind the scenes for me?

I know this is a lot but I hope it makes sense.... thanks

Comment: How were you adding the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField  unless you have an excellent reason (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

The following schema would be generated for your fields in DB

```
event character varying(200),
tool character varying(200),
other character varying(200) NOT NULL,
protocol character varying(200) NOT NULL,
```

This would mean that you can enter "NULL" values in database for 'event' and 'tool' field but not for 'other' and 'protocol' fields.

Yet, you can enter a blank text for all the fields irrespective of weather they are "blank=True" or not. Reason being that "Blank=True" is only used by Django for its own validations and its not reflected in Database schema.

Comment: So let me see if I get this. For other and for protocol blank would be allowed but not stored in the Database?   What about event or tool, in the case of a blank value, would something be stored in the database scheme?      Also when I used new_member = Member.create() , are all values automatically assigned blank?

Comment: blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required. 
For understanging null behavior,  new_member = Member.objects.create(tool=None) will pass whereas, new_member = Member.objects.create(other=None) will fail.